# I have a class that creates an instance of another class. How do I pass a variable through the first class into the instantiation of the second class?

Tags: c++

I have two classes, Lexer and InputStream. In my main function, I create an instance of Lexer, passing in the string 'filename'. My intention is for Lexer to pass 'filename' into its member variable 'is', so that InputStream::getChar() can read out the characters when Lexer::getString() calls it. I'm not sure how to make this happen, because currently, filename is passed into Lexer just fine, but isn't passed into the constructor of InputStream. How can I get filename into InputStream's constructor?

```
class InputStream
{
public:
    InputStream(string filename)
    {
        in.open(filename);
    }
    char getChar()
    {
        return in.get();
    }
    char nextChar()
    {
        return in.peek();
    }

private:
    ifstream in;
};

class Lexer
{
public:
    Lexer(string filename)
    {
        this->filename = filename;
    }
    string getString()
    {
        while (is.nextChar() != EOF)
        {
            valueSoFar.push_back(is.getChar());
        }
    }

private:
    string valueSoFar;
    string filename;
    InputStream is{filename};
};
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your C++ book should have plenty of examples of classes having other classes as class members, and how to properly construct these class members from their parent class's constructor. You need to read this chapter in your C++ book, and you should be able then to do this correctly.

Comment: @Yucel_K No, I'm only calling open() in the InputStream constructor.

Comment: `Lexer(string filename) : is(filename) { ... }` That said, I'm not sure what the abstraction really buys you.

Comment: so  what is the purpose behind storing the file name in lexer? on a side note can you edit your post and add minimal minimal, complete verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `InputStream is{filename}` happens before the constructor of the Lexer `Lexer(string filename)`, meaning the Lexer's `filename` is not not yet assigned a value when the InputStream is constructed. That's likely your problem. Also getChar is likely intended to return a char, not a string.  It doesn't compile as given.  You can use Retired Ninja's suggestion of `Lexer(string filename : is(filename) { /* other code here */ }`

Comment: `InputStream is{filename};` won't work because  the Lexer constructor is called after the constructor of InputStream  is called. Maddy answered your question below. but.. your code still won't work. you are trying to push_back onto a string.  `valueSoFar.push_back(is.getChar())` . you also returning nothing although the function suppose to return a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can initialize Inputstream instance like below within Lexer Class Constructor

```
class Lexer
{
    public:
    Lexer(string filename)
    : is(filename)
    {
        this->filename = filename;
    }
    string getString()
    {
        valueSoFar.push_back(is.getChar());
    }

    private:
    string valueSoFar;
    string filename;
    InputStream is;
};
```

Comment: The initializer suggestion is good.  But also be careful of other errors: the return type of is.getChar()  (which returns a string in the original post) isn't compatible with valueSoFar.push_back (which expects a char)

Comment: Oops! Looks like in the minimization of my code I messed that up. I edited it.